# Why my compiled folder has an sub folder named as stick package path

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

After I build my project use maven, I find the strange thing below:

[image]

and in the windows explorer it looks like below:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this happend and how can I make them in one folder?

Thanks!

==========================================================

Add:

Thank for @Antoniossss helping me find where the problem is.

After some test, I get the source of the problem:

In intellij, when you try to add a package dir belong to `java` folder

if you haven't make the the directory `src/java` as a Sources Root, then your action to add a package dir like `org.mytest.mysourcecode` will just create one flat folder named `org.mytest.mysourcecode`.

else if you make the directory as a Source Root then add a package dir, Intellij will automatically create a structure thing like `org`(folder) -> `mytest`(folder) -> `mysourcecode`(folder).

the second situation is what we want.

Hope this will help to you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in one case you have named (most probably resources) youd directory exactly `com.zautarian` while you probably think that you have created structured package tree and intellij is displaying it "flat" for user comfort. Had the same issue 2 days ago.

Check the project structure in explorer and you will se that you have resources in directory named `com.zautarian`

Comment: Absolutely right! this problem make a lot of mistake in my program, thank you for helping me fix the problem.